# How to modify an array before the render

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I would like to change the value of my array to display the new array before the render.
I use componentWillMount to call my function firstly.
My function change the array in the function

```js
import recipeData from '../Helpers/RecipeData'

componentWillMount(){
    this._selectRicipe()
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        myRecipeData: recipeData
    }
}

_selectRicipe(){
    for (let i = 0; i < recipeData.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.props.listIngredients.length; j++) {
            if (this.props.listIngredients[j].name == recipeData[i].type) {
                newData = []
                console.log(this.props.listIngredients[j].name)
                newData = recipeData[i].name
                this.setState({ myRecipeData: newData })
                console.log("new RecipeData 1 : " + this.state.myRecipeData[i].name)
            }
        }
    }
}

render() {
    console.log("..New..recipe.. " + this.state.myRecipeData[0].name);
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.myRecipeData}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <RecipeDesc recipeData={item} />}
        >
        </FlatList>
    )
}
```

Into my RecipDesc component I get the data in fact I can get the values of the first unmodified array
I tried to send the new array since an another view with 
Maybe I need to use async operation ?

Thank you

Comment: Hii, try newdata.push(recipeData[i].name) instead of newData = recipeData[i].name

Comment: I have this fallowing error "undefined is not an object" error located here 
 data={this.state.myRecipeData}
   keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
   renderItem={({item}) => <RecipeDesc
   recipeData={item}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at your code, I find you setState in a loop, it will affect your app performance. I modify it like below

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
    myRecipeData: recipeData
}
}  

//please do it in the componentDidMount
componDidMount() {
 this._selectRicipe()
}

_selectRicipe(){
let newData = [] // avoid to define a object in the loop repeately
for (let i = 0; i < recipeData.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < this.props.listIngredients.length; j++){
        if(this.props.listIngredients[j].name == recipeData[i].type){
            console.log(this.props.listIngredients[j].name)
            newData.push(recipeData[i].name)
             // the flatlist neeed data is arry and not loop to 
             //   setState
            // this.setState({ myRecipeData: newData }) 
            console.log("new RecipeData 1 : 
           "+this.state.myRecipeData[i].name)
            }
    }
```

}
  this.setState({ myRecipeData: newData })  }

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
 // put this in componentDidMount()
    this.state = {
            myRecipeData: recipeData,
            newData:[],          
        }
```

and in your _selectRicipe,

```
    _selectRicipe(){
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.myRecipeData.length; i++) {
                for(let j = 0; j < this.props.listIngredients.length; j++){
                    if(this.props.listIngredients[j].name == recipeData[i].type){
                        console.log(this.props.listIngredients[j].name)
                        this.state.newData.push(recipeData[i].name);
                        console.log("new RecipeData 1 : "+this.state.myRecipeData[i].name)
                        }
                }
           }
// Outside of your for loop
     this.setState({
      newData:this.state.newData
    });
        }
```

and set new updated newData in your FlatList..

```
<FlatList
   data={this.state.newData}
   keyExtractor={(item,index) => index}
   renderItem={({item}) => <RecipeDesc
   recipeData={item}
  />}
 >
```

Comment: It can work !! Now I just have to iterate the array with map and fine. Thank you :)